# Locate a button which has a span with specific text in Selenium python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following html snippet:

```
<button><span>Next</span></button>
```

I want to locate this button and I am using the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@span[.='Next']]")
```

Also used:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button//span[.='Next']")
```

but this locates the span instead of the button :(

But no luck with this. Does anyone know what is the correct way for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this XPATH to locate `button` based on child `span` text content

```
"//button[span='Next']"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Next']//parent::button")
```

Comment: what you just shared locates the span and not the button which results in `is not clickable.`